# SOLVED Radio buttons STAR RATING works from right-to-left instead of left-to-right

Tags: html, jquery, css

what is the trick to make a hover work from the leftmost toward the rightmost star?
things such as `flex-direction: row-reverse;` and `direction: rtl;` doesnt count, because they reverse the order of the stars too. since we can't find a way to reverse the loop to go from 5 to 1, we need another solution.

```css
.rating-container input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.rating-container label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating-container svg {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.rating-container input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label svg,
.rating-container label:hover ~ label svg,
.rating-container label:hover svg {
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="rating-rate" class="rating-container" name="revrating">
                        <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="revrating" value="1">
                        <label for="rating1"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="revrating" value="2">
                        <label for="rating2"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="revrating" value="3">
                        <label for="rating3"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="revrating" value="4">
                        <label for="rating4"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="revrating" value="5">
                        <label for="rating5"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span></div>
```

**HTML Generated from a loop:**

```
<div id="rating-rate" class="rating-container" name="revrating">
  {{#for 1 5}}
    {{#if ../product.reviews.selected_rating '===' $index}}
      <input type="radio" id="rating{{$index}}" value="{{$index}}" checked />
      <label for="rating{{$index}}"><svg class="star-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
    {{else}}
      <input type="radio" id="rating{{$index}}" name="revrating" value="{{$index}}" />
      <label for="rating{{$index}}"><svg class="star-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
    {{/if}}
  {{/for}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#rating-rate span').on('click', function(){
   $('#rating-rate span').removeClass('active');
    var stars = $(this).find('input').val();
     for (i = 1; i <= stars; i++) {
       $('#rating'+i).parent().addClass('active');
     } 
     
  });
});
```

```css
.rating-container input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.rating-container label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating-container svg {
  fill: #ccc;
}

span:has(~:hover) > label svg{
     fill: #000;
}


span:hover label svg{
  fill: #000;
}


 #rating-rate span.active  label svg {
     fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="rating-rate" class="rating-container" name="revrating">
                          <span>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="revrating" value="1">
                            <label for="rating1"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="revrating" value="2">
                            <label for="rating2"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="revrating" value="3">
                            <label for="rating3"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="revrating" value="4">
                            <label for="rating4"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="revrating" value="5">
                            <label for="rating5"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            </span>
                        <span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span></div>
```

Comment: this works, but what about the "checked" state ? the hover works but does nothing on click..

Comment: do you have a solution for the checked state ?

Comment: @Quanton Please checked Updated Code

Comment: that solution works only for 1-2 clicks, then it stops and brakes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the :has operator? Is kinda new but allows for this kind of selections. It allows you to select each element with a certain characteristic, in your case, all stars having a later sibling with :hover.
This code should make the trick

```css
    label:has(~:hover)>svg,
    label:hover>svg{
       fill: #000;
    }
```

Comment: Just be aware that currently :has is implemented on Firefox only if the user has set a flag.

Comment: [link](https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/css-has) if we check here it shows that all the new browsers already implemented that

Comment: @Quanton not sure what is meant by all new browsers, but just to reiterate, FF requires the user to set a flag. Hopefully it will become standard in FF soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `direction: rtl;` but you need to reverse the radio value so the first one is `5` until `1` is the last

```js
// For testing only (To see the selected value)
setInterval(() => {  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="revrating"]:checked')?.value)
}, 1000)
```

```css
.rating-container {
  direction: rtl;
  width: fit-content;
}

.rating-container input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.rating-container label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating-container svg {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.rating-container input[type="radio"]:checked~label svg,
.rating-container label:hover~label svg,
.rating-container label:hover svg {
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="rating-rate" class="rating-container" name="revrating">
  <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="revrating" value="5">
  <label for="rating5"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="revrating" value="4">
  <label for="rating4"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="revrating" value="3">
  <label for="rating3"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="revrating" value="2">
  <label for="rating2"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="revrating" value="1">
  <label for="rating1"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span></div>
```

Comment: OP said "`direction: rtl;` doesnt count" [sic].

Comment: But used with reversed radio works.

Answer (score 0):

Make the container of the `<input>`s, `<label>`s, and `<svg>`s a flex container and then reverse it's direction by adding the following CSS:

```css
.rating-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Next, reverse the order of the values on each `<input>`:

```html
<input ... value="5">
<input ... value="4">
<input ... value="3">
<input ... value="2">
<input ... value="1">
```

If the HTML cannot be altered simply assign the values programmatically after the page has loaded:

```
// Plain JavaScript
document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio]").forEach((r, i, a) => {
  r.value = a.length - i;
}); 
// OR
// jQuery
$(":radio").each(function(i) {
  let size = $(":radio").length;
  $(this).val(size - i);
});
```

In the example below, the container is `<form id="rating">`, the names have been slightly changed for simplicity but the HTML layout has not. Some JavaScript was added to demonstrate that the correct value is assigned when the user picks a star.

This example will submit the checked value to a live test server.

**Directions**

1. Click a <kbd>★</kbd>.
2. Note the value displayed in console.
3. Click the <kbd>Send</kbd> button.
4. Note the server response displayed in the iframe below.

```js
// For demonstration purposes
const main = document.forms.rating;

main.onchange = e => console.log(e.target.value);

Array.from(main.elements.rating).forEach((r, i, a) => r.value = a.length - i);

/* This version will work specifically for OP code */

// document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio']").forEach((r, i, a) => r.value = a.length - i);

/* This is a jQuery version of the previous line */

/*
$(":radio").each(function(i) {
  let size = $(":radio").length;
  $(this).val(size - i);
});
*/
```

```css
#rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

[name="rating"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg {
  fill: #ccc;
}

[name="rating"]:checked~label svg,
label:hover~label svg,
label:hover svg {
  fill: #000;
}


/* All of the proceeding CSS is for demonstration purposes */

button {
  margin-left: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!-- Attributes "action", "method", and "target" are for
demonstration purposes -->
<form id="rating" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target="response">
  <!-- button is for demonstration purposes -->
  <button>Send</button>
  <input id="rating1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1">
  <label for="rating1"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input id="rating2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2">
  <label for="rating2"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input id="rating3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3">
  <label for="rating3"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input id="rating4" name="rating" type="radio" value="4">
  <label for="rating4"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
  <input id="rating5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5">
  <label for="rating5"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
</form>
<!-- iframe is for demostration purposes -->
<iframe name="response"></iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I mentioned that using flex-direction: row-reverse; and direction: rtl; are not an option, because then when you click on 4 it submits 2, you click 5 it submits 1, because it is all reversed not only the hover but the order as well. If you inspect your solution, you will see what i mean. Visually that is correct, but on the back side its wrong.

Comment: The backside will receive the value of the `<input>` that is checked. Look at what the console displays when you click a star.

Comment: @Quanton Here's a [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/N33t081/Screenshot-2023-06-28-031107.png)

Comment: yeah i see, your solution is perfect for those who want to change the html code, since we have a loop that somehow works only for ++ , we can't change it to go 5 to 1.  I think that we solved that with a little jQuery script right now, without changing the order

Comment: You should add that your HTML is dynamically generated (which is trivial).

Comment: @Quanton updated with a simple JavaScript  and equivalent jQuery solution which does not require the HTML to be changed. 3 lines of CSS and 3 lines of jQuery (or 1 line of JS).

Comment: You said I should add that our HTML is dynamically generated, I agree with you. I have added the original loop code to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how we solved our problem with the wrong hover and select direction.**

(css solution provided by **Giuliano Gostinfini** & **Mitali Patel**, thank you)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating-container input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var selectedRating = $(this).val();
    $('.rating-container label svg').each(function(index) {
      if (index < selectedRating) {
        $(this).css('fill', '#000');
      } else {
        $(this).css('fill', '#ccc');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.rating-container input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }

    .rating-container label {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .rating-container svg {
      fill: #ccc;
    }

    label:has(~:hover) > svg, label:hover > svg {
         fill: #000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-rate" class="rating-container" name="revrating">
                            <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="revrating" value="1">
                            <label for="rating1"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="revrating" value="2">
                            <label for="rating2"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="revrating" value="3">
                            <label for="rating3"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="revrating" value="4">
                            <label for="rating4"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="revrating" value="5">
                            <label for="rating5"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="1.697 1.992 11.58 11" role="img" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M13.277 6.182 9.697 8.782 11.057 12.992 7.487 10.392 3.907 12.992 5.277 8.782 1.697 6.182 6.117 6.182 7.487 1.992 8.857 6.182 13.277 6.182Z"></path></svg></label>
                        <span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display: none;"></span></div>
```

Comment: How is this a pure css solution when you are using JavaScript

Comment: We tried to solve it with pure css, unfortunately that doesn't do the job. the order is incorrect or the hover is wrong. We decided to use a little bit of script to get it done.

Comment: You could just write them in descending order and use `flex`. That would be a far better solution that writing JS which is very slow than CSS and I think it would be still in order (descending).

Comment: Normally yes, but in our case we have a loop that generates that order from 1 to 5 and we can't manage to change that go from 5 to 1. we tried different techniques but none of them work.

Comment: I have added the loop code to the main post.